# show the contents of a text file in my html file using php

Tags: php, html

I have a div within an html page in which I want to load the contents of verslag.text. I’ve tried to use fread of include but I can’t get it to work.

My text file contains:

```
07-Jun-2019 21:41,vrijdag,dfwnfql,8
07-Jun-2019 21:43,vrijdag,rfqe,
07-Jun-2019 22:10,vrijdag,kjvwekvn,
```

I would like to change that to text with html tags like:

```
<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<th>Japan</th>
</tr>
```

So I can use some html make-up.

I've got the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="middev"><p>buttonclass="knop"type="button"name="divindex">Home</button>
<button class="knop"type="button"name="toonverslag">Verslag</button>
<button class="knop" type="button" name="route">Route</button>
<button class="knop" type="button" name="links">Links</button></p>
<p>test tekst</p>
<p><?php include 'verslag.text';
echo "testing"?></p>
</div>
```

How can I show the contents of the text file on my webpage and what should I do the get the html tags processed?

Answer (score 0):

First you must use not html pages to load this text page.You can use like following

### text.php

```
<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<th>Japan</th>
</tr>
```

### main.php

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="middev"><p>buttonclass="knop"type="button"name="divindex">Home</button>
<button class="knop"type="button"name="toonverslag">Verslag</button>
<button class="knop" type="button" name="route">Route</button>
<button class="knop" type="button" name="links">Links</button></p>
<p>test tekst</p>

<p><?php include 'text.php'; ?> // set the path of text.php 
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dhanushka sasanka,

So, I include my text.php in mijn main.php. But how do I load the main.php. I use a button to load the page with the div. Should I instead call the main.php and put all my html code in teh main php?

The page where I want to use this code is: 
https://lodysreizen.nl/toonverslag_old.html

Comment: i can't get your idea .i think you want to load that main page from your button click nh? So do as following .you are asking very basic html.
```<a href="main.php"><button class="knop" type="button" name="divindex">Home</button>
</a> ```

Answer (score -1):

you can read a text file and output line by line using:

```
$file = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($file) {
  while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
      echo $line."<br>";
  }

  fclose($handle);
}else{
      echo "File does not exist!";}
```

Comment: hi Cristi bejan,

I do not understand echo enough yet.
This code let me read teh file line by line with a <br> on the end.

Where does the echo output go to? Do I need a textbox ot something and does the echo reciever understands html tags?

Comment: Echo îs what you can use în php to output a string. All the html tags are understanded, so you can have somting like echo "<p>Some string</p>" and the paragraph Will be rendered on the page

Comment: If you what to concatenate the string with a variabile you write it: echo "<p> Some string ". $var. "</p>" ;